# iPhone, is it possible to remove the back button and make a view slide up?

Tags: iphone

I have a view which I'm reusing (its a date range selection screen) it elsewhere in my app, its the only view and there isn't any other views to navigate too. So theres no back button.

I'm trying to reuse the screen to select a date range in another part of my app. I call it from a done button on the previous view. However, I'd rather it appeared like a dialog. Also my title is too big and if I have a back button it doesn't fit.

So can i remove the back button, is my main question?

Also can i make the view slide up from the bottom of the screen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can present the view modally by putting it in another view controller and having it slide up from the bottom of the screen like so:

```
[self presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:YES];
```

The default is sliding up but you can change it with the modalTransitionStyle property of the modal view controller.

Using a modal presentation may fix your first problem as well, since you will need a whole view controller rather than just the view and it will cover the entire screen.